# CSS: Заданный цвет и отображаемый цвет отличаются

Tags: css

Чем можно объяснить феномен различия заданного в CSS цвета и отображаемого цвета? Плагины для Chrome для получения цвета дают одинаковые значения, но они отличаются от того, что заданы в `css`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#div{
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background: #302e36;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: У меня этот стоит, даёт правильный цвет. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eye-dropper/hmdcmlfkchdmnmnmheododdhjedfccka

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev, установил. У меня даёт `#343239` с квадрата при запуске со сниппета (как и другие плагины расширения).

Comment: Предположу, что это из-за цветового профиля макета, из которого вы брали этот цвет. В зависимости от профиля цвета могут отличаться от веба.

Comment: Попробовал в Firefox. Там с его плагинами всё нормально.

Comment: Может у вас какой-то плагин в хроме меняет цвета?) другого объяснения не вижу.